# CSS bug: Review page inconsistant

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

[image: Bug]

I'm pretty sure the 2 shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed for FireFox 11.0.  Seems to be for answers that show up in `/review`.

<sub>*I'm really sick of this really high version number nonsense*</sub>

Comment: same here......

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the css so the answer vote # aligns with the stats of questions.  The change will be in the next production build.